# Need to render UITextView full content to PDF

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pdf, uitextview

I have the following method that works fine in my @implementation UIView (SaveToPdf) class

```
- (NSData *) toPdfData
{
// Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

// Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, self.bounds, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


// draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData
[self.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

// remove PDF rendering context
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

return pdfData;
}
```

I use this method to print my view to PDF and it works fine except one problem. My view contain a UITextView and the pdf only prints the visible area of that UITextView. I need the PDF to render the full content (i.e scrollable text)

I am new to iOS development, I would appreciate if someone can please point me in the right direction.

*One thing to note, I have other subviews in the UIView (labels, textfields etc.) that needs to be printed to that PDF as well. This currently works fine and the layout is preserved in my PDF simply using [self.layer renderInContext:pdfContext]; since the main view will loop over all it's subviews..

Thank you

Comment: you need to creat PDF drowline and drowRect then you can save as a pdf you can get this

Comment: why the downvotes? trying to be good to new-comers. Upvoting to compensate for the downvotes...

Answer (score 1):

I know of 2 approaches -

1. I have seen some code where `[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];` was being done. When I tried I saw that it was causing me to loose text clarity. So I could not use this method.
2. This is the more traditional method. i.e. you extract text and draw it. This code is rock solid and has seen some usage. So all you need to do is get all the text from your `uitextview` and pass it here...

Hope this helps.

```
#define kBorderInset 25.0
#define kMarginInset 15.0

- (void) drawText
{
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

NSString *textToDraw = @"YOUR TEXT FROM UITEXTVIEW HERE";
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];

CGSize stringSize = [textToDraw sizeWithFont:font
                           constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset) 
                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset + 350.0, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSize.height);

[textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect 
              withFont:font
         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap
             alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick Answer Srikar. The one thing I need to note is my UIView have other things in addition to the UITextView...I have labels, textfields etc...the [self.layer renderInContext:pdfContext]; was recursively printing all subviews and it made things easy. Having said that, how would I be able to have this code triggered only when the UITextView is about to be render...and leave the rest of the subviews intact

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with drawing as much text as fits on your page and you're having troubles with text from your UITextView being cut-off in the PDF, you want to disable scrolling of the UITextView. Either in Interface Builder or programmatically:

```
textview.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

When scrollEnabled is set to `YES`, the text got cut off in my PDFs. Without scrolling, I get the whole text - at least as much as will fit on one page anyways.

If you need the text to spawn over multiple pages, I think you have to resort to drawing your elements individually onto the PDF drawing context as the other answers show.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this code to generate pdf from UIView contents.
May this will help you.

```
#define kBorderInset            20.0
#define kBorderWidth            1.0
#define kMarginInset            10.0

//Line drawing
#define kLineWidth              1.0

    - (IBAction)generatePdfButtonPressed
{
 pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, 792);
 NSString *fileName = @"profileInfo.pdf";
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

 [self generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFileName];
}

- (void) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath
{
 UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

 NSInteger currentPage = 0;
 BOOL done = NO;
 do
 {
  // Mark the beginning of a new page.
  UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

  // Draw a page number at the bottom of each page.
  currentPage++;
  [self drawPageNumber:currentPage];

  //Draw a border for each page.
  [self drawBorder];

  //Draw text fo our header.
  [self drawHeader];

  //Draw a line below the header.
  [self drawLine];

  //Draw some text for the page.
  if (profileInfo!=nil) 
  {
   NSString *stringwithInfo=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Headline: %@\nFirstname: %@\nLastName : %@\nSiteStandardProfileRequest:\n%@",[profileInfo valueForKey:@"headline"],[profileInfo valueForKey:@"firstName"],[profileInfo valueForKey:@"lastName"],[[profileInfo valueForKey:@"siteStandardProfileRequest"]valueForKey:@"url"]];


   [self drawText:stringwithInfo];
  }

  //Draw an image
  [self drawImage];
  done = YES;
 }
 while (!done);

 // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
 UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}

- (void) drawBorder
{
 CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor brownColor];
 CGRect rectFrame = CGRectMake(kBorderInset, kBorderInset, pageSize.width-kBorderInset*2, pageSize.height-kBorderInset*2);
 CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currentContext, borderColor.CGColor);
 CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, kBorderWidth);
 CGContextStrokeRect(currentContext, rectFrame);
}


- (void) drawLine
{
 CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

 CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, kLineWidth);

 CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currentContext, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

 CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(kMarginInset + kBorderInset, kMarginInset + kBorderInset + 40.0);
 CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(pageSize.width - 2*kMarginInset -2*kBorderInset, kMarginInset + kBorderInset + 40.0);

 CGContextBeginPath(currentContext);
 CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
 CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

 CGContextClosePath(currentContext);
 CGContextDrawPath(currentContext, kCGPathFillStroke);
}


- (void) drawText:(NSString*)txtTodraw
{
 CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

 UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

 CGSize stringSize = [txtTodraw sizeWithFont:font
                            constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset)
                                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

 CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset + 50.0, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSize.height);

 [txtTodraw drawInRect:renderingRect
               withFont:font
          lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap
              alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
}


- (void) drawImage
{
 UIImage * demoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"demo.png"];
 [demoImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( (pageSize.width - demoImage.size.width/2)/2, 350, demoImage.size.width/2, demoImage.size.height/2)];
}


- (void) drawHeader
{
 CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.3, 0.7, 0.2, 1.0);

 NSString *textToDraw = @"LinkedIn Profile Info";

 UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0];

 CGSize stringSize = [textToDraw sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

 CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSize.height);

 [textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
}


- (void)drawPageNumber:(NSInteger)pageNumber
{
 NSString* pageNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %d", pageNumber];
 UIFont* theFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

 CGSize pageNumberStringSize = [pageNumberString sizeWithFont:theFont
                                            constrainedToSize:pageSize
                                                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

 CGRect stringRenderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset,
                                         pageSize.height - 40.0,
                                         pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset,
                                         pageNumberStringSize.height);

 [pageNumberString drawInRect:stringRenderingRect withFont:theFont lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
}

-(void)fillInformationInform:(NSDictionary*)dics
{
 headLineLabel.text=[dics valueForKey:@"headline"];
 NSURL *picUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:[dics valueForKey:@"pictureUrl"]];
 profileImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:picUrl]];

 phoneNoLabel.text=[[[[dics valueForKey:@"phoneNumbers"] valueForKey:@"values"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"phoneNumber"];

 cityLabel.text=[[dics valueForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"name"];
 emailAddressLabel.text=[dics valueForKey:@"emailAddress"];
 nameLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[dics valueForKey:@"firstName"],[dics valueForKey:@"lastName"]];

 dateOfBirthLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-%@",[[dics valueForKey:@"dateOfBirth"]valueForKey:@"day"],[[dics valueForKey:@"dateOfBirth"]valueForKey:@"month"],[[dics valueForKey:@"dateOfBirth"]valueForKey:@"year"]];

 NSDictionary *eduDic=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[[[dics valueForKey:@"educations"]valueForKey:@"values"]objectAtIndex:0]];

// NSLog(@"education dic is %@",eduDic);

 degreeLabel.text=[eduDic valueForKey:@"degree"];
 durationLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"From %@ To %@",[[eduDic valueForKey:@"startDate"]valueForKey:@"year"],[[eduDic valueForKey:@"endDate"]valueForKey:@"year"]];
 fieldOfStudyLabel.text=[eduDic valueForKey:@"fieldOfStudy"];
 collegeLabel.text=[eduDic valueForKey:@"schoolName"];


 destinationLabel.text=[[[[dics valueForKey:@"positions"] valueForKey:@"values"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"title"];

 NSArray *skillsArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[dics valueForKey:@"skills"]valueForKey:@"values"]];


 NSString *skillStr=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@""];

 for (NSDictionary *skillDic in skillsArray) 
 {
  if (![skillStr isEqualToString:@""]) {
   skillStr=[skillStr stringByAppendingFormat:@","];
  }
  skillStr=[skillStr stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",[[skillDic valueForKey:@"skill"]valueForKey:@"name"]];
 }

 NSLog(@"skill string is %@",skillStr);

 skillsLable.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",skillStr];

}
```

Comment: Thanks Hercules. I might fall back to this, the only issue I was hoping to avoid is to manually render each element of the PDF. My view have images, labels, text etc...going this route will mean that I need to redraw the whole layout in the PDF myself and resort/position everything they way it looks in the view...correct?